# Symfony2 - Securing the whole frontend (staging)

Tags: security, symfony, staging

I would like to upload my website to a staging server and secure the whole site with a password.

I managed to secure the backend but I don't know how to secure the frontend.
Symfony's firewall doesn't seem to be meant for this purpose.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The web hosting company my allow you to setup specific firewalls and only allow a single IP to load the page.  The front end will not be secure, but no one will be able to access it except you.  AWS and other large firms offer it easily.

Comment: You can secure any part of you application using Symfony's firewalls, could you please paste the content of your security.yml in here ?